# JavaScript OAuth2 flow for Azure AD v2 login does not give an access_token

Tags: javascript, hapi.js, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm using [bell](https://github.com/hapijs/bell) and [hapijs](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi) and trying to get the [office365 provider](https://github.com/hapijs/bell/blob/master/Providers.md#office-365) to work, but it seems like the https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token endpoint isn't giving me the `access_token` required for getting profile information.

This is the OAuth 2.0 flow I'm seeing:

First it redirects to

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id=[client-id]
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5430%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Flogin%2Fazure-ad
&state=[state]
&scope=openid%20offline_access%20profile
```

in [oauth.js#L197](https://github.com/hapijs/bell/blob/v8.8.0/lib/oauth.js#L197)

After a successful sign in from the Microsoft login, it redirects to the server and bell does a POST to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token with payload

```
{
  payload: 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=[code]&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5430%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Flogin%2Fazure-ad&client_id=[client-id]&client_secret=[client-secret]',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
}
```

in [oauth.js#L242](https://github.com/hapijs/bell/blob/v8.8.0/lib/oauth.js#L242)

This in turn gives me the following response

```
{
  "refresh_token": "MCTrMmd...",
  "id_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV..."
}
```

From the [OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-access-token) documentation, it seems like I should be getting something more like

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik5HVEZ2ZEstZnl0aEV1Q...",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "scope": "https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read",
    "refresh_token": "AwABAAAAvPM1KaPlrEqdFSBzjqfTGAMxZGUTdM0t4B4...",
    "id_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyZDRkMTFhMi1mODE0LTQ2YTctOD...",
}
```

Specifically, I need an `access_token`, because the following profile get request ([oauth.js#L270](https://github.com/hapijs/bell/blob/v8.8.0/lib/oauth.js#L270)) requires it for

```
Authorization: 'Bearer ' + payload.access_token
```

Even in [Calling /token endpoint does not give me an access_token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48800786/calling-token-endpoint-does-not-give-me-an-access-token), it seems like the `/token` request gets more fields in the response.

Is there something I'm missing in the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scopes `openid`, `email`, `profile`, and `offline_access` don't seem to return an `access_token`.

Adding the `User.Read` scope does provide an `access_token`.

For bell, you would need something like:

```
server.auth.strategy('office365', 'bell', {
    provider: 'office365',
    scope: [
        'User.Read'
    ],
    password: 'something',
    clientId: 'clientId',
    clientSecret: 'clientSecret',
});
```

Although, there are still issues with the endpoint that [bell's office365 provider](https://github.com/hapijs/bell/blob/v8.8.0/lib/providers/office365.js#L13) has, documented here: [How do I get the logged in users profile for Azure AD OAuth logins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49449654/how-do-i-get-the-logged-in-users-profile-for-azure-ad-oauth-logins)

Figured this out from the investigation in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49424859/111884.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your first request, it doesn't have the `response_mode=query` header, in contrast to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-access-token):

[image]

In which it also states the expected successful response:
[image]

UPDATE: I was able to replicate this when I don't include the scope in the payload when trying to get the token:
[image]

Including the scope in the payload returns the `access_token`:
[image]

Comment: I just tried this, and it doesn't seem to change anything. The response I got back still only has `refresh_token` and `id_token` without any `access_token`

Comment: In the host url `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`, are you using the common tenant or did you replace it with your tenant id?

Comment: It looks like the payload being sent by bell, doesn't have the scope. I was able to replicate this in postman. Excluding the scope does not return the `access_token`, while including the scope returns the `access_token` as well as the `token_type`.

Comment: Yep, I was using `common` for the tenant. The scope might be the issue actually. Bell does send a scope, but the default is `['openid','offline_access', 'profile']` (https://github.com/hapijs/bell/blob/v8.8.0/lib/providers/office365.js#L10) - I might need to add some microsoft graph scopes for an access token. I'll give it a go

Comment: It works with the `User.Read` scope, but I'm still having a different issue with figuring out the correct url I'm supposed to call with the `access_token`. I've posted another question about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49449654/how-do-i-get-the-logged-in-users-profile-for-azure-ad-oauth-logins